# How to filter a list?

Tags: c#, sorting, loops, generic-list

This is a method that should take already assigned users out of a list
and keep non-assigned ones in a list. The GuidList has the userId added 
to it on a button click. The profileList is used to populate a gridView.

Here is the code:

```
private VList<VW_profiles> FilterAssigned(VList<VW_profiles> profileList)
{
    VList<VW_profiles> sortedList = new VList<VW_profiles>();
    foreach(VW_profiles profile in profileList)
    {
        if(GuidList.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach(Guid userId in GuidList)
            {
                if(profile.UserId != userId)
                {
                    sortedList.Add(profile)
                }
            }
        }       
        else
        {
            sortedList = profileList;
        }
    }
    return sortedList;
}
```

Now here's my problem. Everythings seems to work well up until 
all of the items in the profileList have also been
added to the GuidList. Then instead of doing a negate on 
the two Guid ID's, we start adding everyone in again. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this is a more effecient way and to avoid the adding in once we've taken everything out.

Thanks!

Comment: But where is **sorting** being handled exactly?

Comment: why not doing this with lambda expressions, it would be much less code, and faster

Comment: I would have wrote a lambda, but I can't understand what your code should do

Comment: I guess I should have said that I was using .net 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in this code:

```
foreach(Guid userId in GuidList)
{
    if(profile.UserId != userId)
    {
        sortedList.Add(profile)
    }
}
```

It should be more like:

```
bool inList = false;
foreach(Guid userId in GuidList)
{
    if(profile.UserId == userId)
    {
        inList = true;
    }
}
if (!inList)
    sortedList.Add(profile)
```

or, the more LINQ-style:

```
bool inList = GuidList.Any(x => x == profile.UserId);
if (!inList)
    sortedList.Add(profile)
```

your current code is more like:

```
GuidList.Where(x => x != profile.UserId)
        .Foreach(x => sortedList.Add(x));
```

which I'm thinking isn't what you want :)

Comment: That was it! I was missing the boolean switch there. I like the ideas of using lambda or LINQ, except I'm working with the 2.0 framework and don't have access to those features.

Answer (score 6):

If `VList<T>` is a `List<T>`, then you can do this:

```
profileList.RemoveAll(profile => GuidList.Contains(profile.UserId));
```

If performance is an issue and there are LOTS of Guids to remove, then you can make GuidList a `HashSet<Guid>`.

**Edit** Based on comments: If you don't want to modify the original list, then do this:

```
var filtered = new VList<VW_profiles>(
    profileList.Where(profile => !GuidList.Contains(profile.UserId)));
```

**Edit** If you are not using a `List<T>`, here is a method you can use on resizable lists implementing `IList<T>` and one you can use on arrays (`T[]`). By only ever removing items from the end of the list, what would be an O(n²) algorithm will be O(n) for most implementations of `IList<T>`.

```
public static void RemoveAll<T>(this IList<T> list, Predicate<T> match)
{
    if (list == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("list");
    if (match == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("match");
    if (list is T[])
        throw new ArgumentException("Arrays cannot be resized.");

    // early out
    if (list.Count == 0)
        return;

    // List<T> provides special handling
    List<T> genericList = list as List<T>;
    if (genericList != null)
    {
        genericList.RemoveAll(match);
        return;
    }

    int targetIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        if (!match(list[i]) && targetIndex != i)
        {
            list[targetIndex] = list[i];
            targetIndex++;
        }
    }

    // Unfortunately IList<T> doesn't have RemoveRange either
    for (int i = list.Count - 1; i >= targetIndex; i--)
    {
        list.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}

public static void RemoveAll<T>(ref T[] array, Predicate<T> match)
{
    if (array == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("array");
    if (match == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("match");

    int targetIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        if (!match(array[i]) && targetIndex != i)
        {
            array[targetIndex] = array[i];
            targetIndex++;
        }
    }

    if (targetIndex != array.Length)
    {
        Array.Resize(ref array, targetIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, although note that this will modify the **original** list. I am not sure if that is intended.